# Rails Stack Level Too Deep With after_update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make it so that if a user changes either of two boolean variables (`buyer` and `seller`, they can be changed in either direction to trigger the action) it will reset the status of a third variable `status_confirmed` to `false`.

I have the following in my `user` model:

```
after_update :reset_confirmed

  def reset_confirmed
    if self.buyer_changed? || self.seller_changed?
      self.update_attributes(status_confirmed: false)
    end
  end
```

From what I can understand `stack level too deep` errors are due to infinite loops or recursions, which I can't find.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2 ways to handle this:

```
after_update :reset_confirmed
def reset_confirmed
  self.update_column(:status_confirmed, false) if self.buyer_changed? || self.seller_changed?
end
```

The difference between `update_attribute` and `update_column` is what will help you, as the latter `skips` callbacks if any.

OR

```
before_save  :reset_confirmed
def reset_confirmed
  self.status_confirmed = false if self.buyer_changed? || self.seller_changed?
end
```

Here, you are just assigning a value before saving it to db, so...

Hope it helps..

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you!