# SystemStackError: stack level too deep - Database Transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a test for an Active Record Transaction. 
The method raising the error looks like this;

```
after_save :process_transaction_fees

def process_transaction_fees
    if self.status == "SUCCESS"
      transaction_fees = 0.0299 #improve after success
      merchant = Business.find_by_id(self.business_id)

      transaction_charges = (self.amount * transaction_fees).to_f

      balance = merchant.balance
      balance_before = merchant.balance
      balance_after = (balance_before.to_f - transaction_charges.to_f)

      merchant_deposit = BusinessTransaction.new(business_id: self.business_id ,amount: transaction_charges, balance_before: balance_before, balance_after: balance_after, status: "SUCCESS")
      merchant.balance = (balance.to_f - transaction_charges.to_f)

      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        merchant.save!
        merchant_deposit.save!
      end
    end
  end
```

However, I keep getting the error  **`SystemStackError:  stack level too deep`** on the line `merchant.save!`.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `.save!` it is going under `after_save` `callback` recursively throwing that error.
Two ways to solve this..both are already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43797111/6548745) which you can refer.