# stack level to deep in rails callback function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I am trying to call a function using callback every time after creation of the record and updating of the record, which callback function I should use so that it will not give me **stack level to deep error**
my model code is

```
class T < ApplicationRecord

  before_commit :calculate
  before_update :calculate  

  def calculate
    t = get_w + get_t + get_a
    self.amount = t
    self.save!

  end

  def get_w
  end

  def get_a
  end

  def get_t
  end

end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Stack Level Too Deep With after\_update method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797001/rails-stack-level-too-deep-with-after-update-method)

Answer (score 3):

At least one of your callbacks is being called again (and thus, recursively) when you call `save!` method. Just try removing that line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are having is that you have a 'before_update' and then you are calling save that triggers the before update. And that is calling again the same method

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

```
class T < ApplicationRecord

  before_commit :calculate
  before_update :calculate  
  def calculate
    t = get_w + get_t + get_a
    self.amount = t
    #self.save! comment this line, because it call `before_commit` callback again and again 

  end

  def get_w
  end

  def get_a
  end

  def get_t
  end

end
```